# Prism cross platform navigation

Tags: wpf, xamarin.forms, prism

I have a PCL with view-models shared between WPF and Xamarin.Forms apps.

On Xamarin Forms I have the INavigationService, which works great. But I don't have something similar on WPF as far as I know.

Any ideas or quick examples how to have a cross platform navigation in the PCL (Portable class library)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would never recommend sharing a WPF VM with a mobile VM, unless that WPF app is just your mobile app running on WPF, even then I would take a different approach.  XF and WPF are vastly different and there is no common navigation paradigm you share across the platforms.  If you must do this, simply create a base VM that has all the business logic, and then create a platform specific VM that derives from the base that would handle the platform navigation.

Comment: Thanks. If I do this as I described, I still need an abstraction over the navigation.

Comment: If it happens that on this app the navigation is the same, would you still not recommend sharing the VMs?

Comment: There is no shared navigation interface between Prism for WPF and prism fro Xamarin.Forms, so you cannot share the VMs if you place nav code in there.

Comment: yes, I understand it doesn't exist. I was thinking I could create an abstraction over the two such that I can use the abstraction in the shared PCL with the view-models.